# Criar botao play/pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso criar um botão estilo o do youtube de play e pause encima do vídeo. Gostaria que quando não clicar nele ele fique parado com o play ai clica nele ele inicia o vídeo.

Código:

```
<video class="video" id="my-video" controls preload="auto" tabindex="0">
```

Eu já tenho a funcionalidade de quando clicar no video ele começar a carregar. Eu queria mesmo saber como colocar aquele icone do play estilo o do youtube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

olha, você não precisa do jQuery para isto, a propria API do JavaScript lhe dá total controle sobre o Video.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var play = document.getElementById("play");
var currentTime = document.getElementById("currentTime");
var duration = document.getElementById("duration");
var timezone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

play.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (video.ended) 
    video.currentTime = 0;
  video.play();
});

video.addEventListener('play', function () {
  play.style.display = "none";
});

video.addEventListener('pause', function () {
  play.style.display = "inline-block";
});

video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
  play.style.display = "inline-block";
});

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
  updateDuracao();
});

var timeToString = function (time) {
  var pad = "000";
  var tempo = new Date((time * 1000) + timezone);
  var millis = tempo.getMilliseconds().toString();
  tempo = tempo.toLocaleTimeString();
  millis = pad.substring(0, pad.length - millis.length) + millis;
  return tempo + "." + millis;
}

var updateDuracao = function () {
  currentTime.textContent = timeToString(video.currentTime);
  duration.textContent = timeToString(video.duration);
};

if (video.readyState > 0) {
  updateDuracao();
} else {
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', updateDuracao);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="play" type="button" value="Play" />
  <span id="currentTime"></span>/<span id="duration"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <video id="video" controls preload="metadata">
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: eu coloquei ela encima do player de video e quando eu clicar nela quero q ela some que e por que dei o play e quando clicar de novo que e o pause quero que ela apareca o que posso implementar para fazer isto?

Comment: Leonardo Costa, você não precisa dois `button`, basta alternar o valor de acordo com o estado do video.

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, agora o exemplo está completo, dê uma olhada.

Comment: cara acho que voce nao intendeu eu so quero que quando eu clicar no botao ele suma nao aparece na tela quandor der play para nao atrapalhar o video esse botao eu vou colocar encima do video e quando clicar nele ou no video ele vai sumir pra pessoa assistir o video sem o botao na frente nesse exemplo que voce deu ele ira continuar encima so que desta vez com o tempo eu so queria que ele esconde-se quando clicado se puder ajudar agradeco e obrigado pela resposta

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, pronto.

Comment: blz valeu eu tinha conseguido antes era so por o onclick mas valeu mesmo assim so que tem um problema como faco para ele aparecer de novo se eu clicar na imagem ou no proprio botao do player? eu so adicionei isso no input: onclick="document.getElementById('button').style.display = 'none';"

Comment: @LeonardoCosta por isto coloquei no evento `pause` e `ended` do video, para que sempre que o video pare o botão `play` reapareça

Comment: intendi deu certo obrigado

Answer (score 1):

**Fiz deste jeito**
colocado dois botoes na primeira DIV, depois o video e com o JS eu fiz uma função passando como parametro para chamar a mesma o ID, dentro da função criei uma const video e coloquei o oncontextmenu para o usuario não poder baixar o video, dai só colocar o querySelector chamando o onclick com o atributo e ID, para desta forma pegar exatamente o que quero

```
<div>
    <button wm-play="meuVideo">Play</button>
    <button wm-pause="meuVideo">Pause</button>
</div>

<video id="meuVideo">
   <source src="http://ovideoquevocequer/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
function configurarVideo(id){
    const video = document.getElementById(id)
    video.oncontextmenu = () => false

    document.querySelector(`[wm-play = ${id}]`).onclick = e => video.play()
    document.querySelector(`[wm-pause = ${id}]`).onclick = e => video.pause()
}
configurarVideo('meuVideo')
</script>
```